# How to pass multiple parameters to reports and export to PDF in JasperReports from Java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to use Jasper Reports to help with reporting in my application. I will have to display my reports in HTML (JSP) and would also need to be able to export the reports to PDF from within my web page.
Most of my reports require multiple parameters, and I can't figure out how to pass them from my Servlet (if I have to pass them there) to the report.

P.S: I'm not using frameworks of any sort, it would be great if you could suggest a framework free implementation.

Comment: @Piotr Nowicki, thanks for the edit! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Preparing data - change this as per your requirement
List<DataDTO> dataDTOList = new ArrayList<DataDTO>();
DataDTO dataDTO = new DataDTO; 
dataDTO.setFirstName("FirstName"); // in your Jasper field name is 'firstName' as type String
dataDTO.setLastName("LastName"); // in your Jasper field name is 'lastName' as type String
dataDTOList.add(dataDTO);

// Adding data
JRDataSource jrdatasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataDTOList);

// Exporting report
File jasperFile = new File("C:/YourReport.jasper"); // change this
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(new FileInputStream(jasperFile.getAbsolutePath()));             
Map parameters = new HashMap();
JRConcurrentSwapFile jrSwapFile = new JRConcurrentSwapFile("C:/PDFOutput/"),30,2);
JRSwapFileVirtualizer virtualizer = new JRSwapFileVirtualizer(2,jrSwapFile,true);
parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, virtualizer);
JasperPrint jpPrintObj = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters,jrdatasource);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jpPrintObj,"C:/PDFOutput/");`
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use HashMap like

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("parameterName","value");
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,map,con);
```

Comment: and how will that help? Sorry Im kinda new to the whole Jasperreport thing.

Comment: I don't know who up voted that, but it doesn't answer my query .

Comment: `HashMap<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
paramMap.put("parameterName","value");                              bytes[] byteStream = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf("myJasperReport.jasper",paramMap,databaseConn);

OutputStream outStream = servletResponse.getOutputStream();
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline, filename=myReport.pdf");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(byteStream.length);
outStream.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);` it might help you.

Comment: I will be using both of the above solutions.

Answer (score 2):

[This example](https://github.com/coding-idiot/jasper-java-examples/tree/master/JSPJasper) will help you, it doesn't require any framework. It exports the report as a PDF. And you can use map as Anil had already explained

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("parameterName","value");
map.put("parameterName2","value2");
map.put("parameterName3","value3");
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,map,con);
```

to pass multiple parameters.

Comment: Your link appears to be dead