# Generate PDF reports through Java(web applications) using iText/ any other library using ready made data

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pdf, itext

*Before* you down vote me, I'm not here to ask on how to use iText in Java. My query is about generate pdf's(reports) using iText. We currently have a set of reports that are prepared in html, is there any way that I could use the data being prepared here to directly generate a pdf rather than write Java code to manually write (Java)code to prepare a table line by line as in the case of iText. A link to an existing solution would suffice as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [JasperReport](http://jasperforge.org/). with this you can create templates and generate `PDFs` dynamically by passing just data. you can use [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport) for designing jasper templates.

Comment: have tried using iReport, but dont know how to pass multiple parameters to the report, I asked this question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709199/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-reports-and-export-to-pdf-in-jasperreports-fr/8733312. but have found no success :(

Comment: responded to your question above

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to iText would be XSL-FO.  You could create a Velocity template for the XSL-FO stylesheet and dynamically populate it with your data.

Comment: No, it's a server side solution.  You'll generate the FO, set the MIME type to "application/pdf", and stream it back to the browser.